# Cross Browser Testing for Website built in Angular Material

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design, browsers, cross-browser-testing

Hi All My Team is developing website on **Angular_Material_Version_1.4**,
I would like to perform **cross browser testing** which includes Different Browsers & there version, is there any specific guidelines for cross browser testing with angular material design..??
What & How should I decide the minimum **version & its type of Browser** for testing.
thanks

Comment: Do you have any requirements from your client/business for what browsers are supposed to be supported?

For Angular, I typically like to use karma-jasmine, personally.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your resources, it might be helpful to have a set of VM's created that have diff combinations of OS's and web browser versions. Determine your threshold for coverage. Look at the latest statistics on browser market share and set up VM's with those browsers that fall within your need. This is far more accurate than running emulators. It takes some resources to set this up, but its worth it in the end to know you have access to all the browsers you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

Cross browser testing can be done with [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com) & [CrossbrowserTesting](http://crossbrowsertesting.com). Both allow a 30 day trial. They have numerous emulators for physical devices.

Chrome allows Toggle Device mode (Ctrl+Shift+M)

Edge has Emulation Mode which can be navigated via inspect element.

I believe [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com)  covers most of the devices and their versions, so we can determine the minimum version and types of browsers from it.

Comment: In my experience emulators don't give exactly the same results as the actual device, but it's often close enough to work with - a combination of testing with emulators and bring your own device usually catches most issues.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Browser stack mentioned above, you may also want to consider http://litmus.com/ which will allow you to cross client test your emails.