# How to implement cross-browser testing in Angular 2 app?

Tags: cross-browser-testing

I'm building an application with Angular2 and using Angular CLI, which works fine so far.

One of the requirements is to implement cross-browser testing. The App is being uploaded on the GitLab repo. I'm used to running a manual cross-browser testing directly on the different browsers before deploying to production.

So, the point which is still not 100% clear for me is how to achieve this kind of implementation of cross-browser and deployment all together on the repo? And how would this work with a GitLab Repo?

I did read the following [post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17643/cross-browser-testing-for-website-built-in-angular-material), but it does not exactly answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the various different selenium drivers that can be used to run against different browsers.  You'll need either the browser or a similar 'browser driver' program, e.g. chromedriver which can be called.
Different browsers can also have different UI and timing issues so you'll need to discover if there are any of them in your app.  You'll want to look into using the cloud and setting up connection to remote servers and services such as browserstack and sauce labs.  Estimated time to implement: 1-3 months.  You should spend time getting it right.  Your automated pipeline is key to success.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I think 1-3 months is a kind of too much time ;-)